# Reload TableView not working on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

i've experience in iOS, but not so much on OS X. Now i have a tableView that should be dynamically updated. I'm using this method to reload the table

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

And i would like that to invoke the delegate

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    // Get a new ViewCell
    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataColumn" owner:self];

...

    return cellView;
}
```

but it doesn't. How could i reload the tableView?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you set delegate and datasource properly of tableview

Comment: yeah i did!i actually pasted the code i used in iOS (revisited for oSX) but it's not working

Comment: Do you implement 'tableView:rowViewForRow:' method in your data source?

Comment: yes of course. But shouldn't it be invoke after reload?

Comment: Did you select view based table view IB? In OSX table views are cell based by default; iOS doesn't have cells so this might have thrown you.

Comment: yes i did, but as soon as the app loads the table view is filled correctly!This means the delegate is called, but then i cannot update it while running the app!

Comment: is self.tableview nil?

Comment: yes, please check you IBOutlet binding for tableView, it should bind to the NSTableview on your IB + delegate and dataSource binding. While reloading the table make sure the self.tableView is not nil(use breakpoints). I hope you are not getting any warnings in the debugger console or delegate methods not implemented.